# Hosting a Python sockets server on the web

Tags: python, socket

I made a simple chat app for my friends and I to use, but I don't want to host the server on my computer, I want to host it on the web. Does anyone know any good services or tutorials on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

as you know
you should run some webserver to serve your python socket on it.
best solution to do this
please install gunicorn and then proxy pass with nginx on it

Python <-> Gunicorn <-> Nginx